# Loading geoJSON in pyspark with Schema validation

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, geojson

I'm trying to create a schema to validate [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) files being loaded:

```
validSchema = StructType([
StructField("type", StringType()),
StructField("geometry", StructType([
  StructField("coordinates", ArrayType(DoubleType())), # POINT
  StructField("coordinates", ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType())))),  # POLYGON
  StructField("coordinates", ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType()))), # LINESTRING
  StructField("type", StringType(), False)
]), False),
StructField("properties", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
])

df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(src_data,mode="PERMISSIVE",schema=validSchema)
```

The problem is that I have three kinds of "coordinates" to satisfy the valid GeoJSON types. However, only the last rule is working, I'm assuming it takes precedence over the previous two based on order.

Is there anyway to specify the schema as saying that one of the coordinate schema must match?

Right now the only way around I can see is to create three schemas and three imports which means scanning all data three times (I have 5TB of data so that seems crazy).

Sample geoJSON data:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[[ -0.144195556640625,52.019120643633386],
        [-0.127716064453125,52.00052411347729],
        [-0.10848999023437499,52.01193653675363],
        [-0.12359619140625,52.02883848153626],
        [-0.144195556640625,52.019120643633386]]]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[-0.196380615234375,52.11283076186275],
      [-0.1263427734375,52.07739600418385]]
      }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-0.1641082763671875, 52.06051241654061]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to specify the schema as saying that one of the coordinate schema must match?

`UserDefinedTypes` (not supported anymore) notwithstanding, all values in a `Column` have to be of the same shape, so you cannot have `array<array<array<double>>>`, `array<array<double>>` and `array<double>` at the same time.

You can skip parsing completely

```
validSchema = StructType([
    StructField("type", StringType()),
    StructField("geometry", StructType([
      StructField("coordinates", StringType()),
      StructField("type", StringType(), False)
    ]), False),
    StructField("properties", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
])
```

And then parse it with `udf` into three separate columns:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import json

@udf("struct<type: string, coordinates: struct<polygon: array<array<struct<lon: double, lat: double>>>, line: array<struct<lon: double, lat: double>>, point: struct<lon: double, lat: double>>>")
def parse(row):
    try:
        struct = json.loads(row["coordinates"])
        t = row["type"]
    except (TypeError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError):
        pass 
    if t == "Polygon":
        return t, (struct, None, None)
    elif t == "LineString":
        return t, (None, struct, None)
    elif t == "Point":
        return t, (None, None, struct)

sdf.select(parse("geometry")).show(truncate=False)
# +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |parse(geometry)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
# +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[Polygon, [[[[-0.144195556640625, 52.019120643633386], [-0.127716064453125, 52.00052411347729], [-0.10848999023437499, 52.01193653675363], [-0.12359619140625, 52.02883848153626], [-0.144195556640625, 52.019120643633386]]],,]]|
# |[LineString, [, [[-0.196380615234375, 52.11283076186275], [-0.1263427734375, 52.07739600418385]],]]                                                                                                                              |
# |[Point, [,, [-0.1641082763671875, 52.06051241654061]]]                                                                                                                                                                           |
# +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you hit the nail on the head by saying it's not possible to have the have the multiple schemas. I will take a play with the function like you describe and feedback here.